# Bijection induced by mapping loops to their circle representations

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a path connected space, and $p \in X$. I wish to show that the map $f \mapsto \tilde{f}$ induces a bijection between the conjugacy classes of $\pi(X,p)$ and $[\mathbb{S}^1: X]$, the free homotopy classes of continuous maps $\mathbb{S}^1 \to X$. Here, $f$ is a loop with base-point $p$ and $\tilde{f}$ is its unique circle representation. My initial guess is to construct the map sending a conjugacy class $\mathcal{C}$ to the circle representation of its representative, then sending that circle representation to its free homotopy equivalence class. Explicitly, $$ \mathcal{C} = [g] \mapsto \tilde{g} \mapsto [\tilde{g}] \in [ \mathbb{S}^1: X].$$ However, I'm not sure that this map is onto since a generic element in $[\mathbb{S}^1: X]$ need not even be a loop. I have thought about remedying this by the following (but I am not sure if there are errors): Take $\tilde{f} \in [\mathbb{S}^1: X]$, define the map $f := \tilde{f} \circ \omega$, where $\omega(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$. Since $X$ is path connected we can always form a new map $f'$ from $f$ that is a loop at $p$ (gluing new paths if necessary). However, I am not sure how to "put" this $f'$ into the correct conjugacy class. By this I mean that I'm not sure how to explicitly write down a pre-image of $\tilde{f}$. Am I on the right track? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "a generic element in $[\mathbb{S}^1:X]$ need not even be a loop"?

Comment: $[\mathbb{S}^1:X]$ is the set of free homotopy classes of continuous maps from $\mathbb{S}^1$ to $X$. Thus, a representative of a class in this set need not be a loop, i.e. its initial and terminal points need not be the same. Since circle representations are defined for loops, this presents a problem in proving surjectivity of the map I proposed.

Comment: What are the "initial" and "terminal" points of a map from $\mathbb{S}^1$ to $X$?

Comment: Taking my $f:= \tilde{f} \circ \omega$, it would be $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, respectively.

Comment: But $\omega(0)=\omega(1)$...

Comment: I see the confusion. I meant $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are the initial and terminal points of $f$, which should be the same since I am trying to construct a loop. The fact that $\tilde{f}$ is just a continuous map $\mathbb{S}^1 \to X $ does not make it a loop, which is where I am having trouble.

Comment: But $f(0)=\tilde{f}(\omega(0))=\tilde{f}(\omega(1))=f(1)$, since $\omega(0)=\omega(1)$.  A loop in $X$ _is_ the same thing as a map $\mathbb{S}^1\to X$.  However, it still isn't obvious that your map is onto, because even though $f(0)=f(1)$, that common value might not be equal to $p$.

Comment: 1) Couldn't you map $\mathbb{S}^1$ to a line segment? So, that would not be a loop in $X$.

2) Since $X$ is path connected, we could glue a path connecting $f(0)=f(1)=a$ to $p$, thus giving a new map $f'$ that is a loop at $p$, correct?

Comment: 1) By what map?  It's still called a loop if $f(0)=f(1)$, even if it doesn't look like a loop because the map isn't injective.  2) Yes; then you have to show $f$ and $f'$ are homotopic.

Comment: Hmm, ok I think I understand my confusion. But I am still not sure how to show this map is onto. Where can I use the fact that we are looking at conjugacy classes? What is special about the conjugacy classes that allow this bijection to exist?

Comment: Conjugacy classes aren't relevant to showing that the map is onto, they are relevant to showing that the map is well-defined.  For the map to be well-defined, you need to show that any two representatives $g,g'$ of the same conjugacy class $\mathcal{C}$ give homotopic maps $\tilde{g},\tilde{g}'$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32212/discussion-between-kevin-sheng-and-eric-wofsey).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me write $\varphi$ for your map taking $[g]$ to $[\tilde{g}]$.  There are three things you have to check to show $\varphi$ is a bijection:

1. $\varphi$ is well-defined: if $[g]=[g']$, then $[\tilde{g}]=[\tilde{g}']$.
2. $\varphi$ is injective: if $[\tilde{g}]=[\tilde{g}']$, then $[g]=[g']$.
3. $\varphi$ is surjective: if $[f]\in[\mathbb{S}^1:X]$, then there exists $g\in \pi_1(X,p)$ such that $[f]=[\tilde{g}]$.

As discussed in the question and in the comments, to prove (3), you note that $f$ can be viewed as a loop in $X$ based at some point $a$, and then concatenate it with a path between $a$ and $p$ on both sides to get a loop $g$ based at $p$.  You then have to check that $\tilde{g}:\mathbb{S}^1\to X$ is homotopic to your map $f$.

Here is an indication of how you prove (2).  If $[\tilde{g}]=[\tilde{g}']$, this means $\tilde{g}$ is homotopic to $\tilde{g}'$, and this homotopy can be viewed as a homotopy $H$ from $g$ to $g'$.  However, this latter homotopy does *not* show $g$ and $g'$ are equal as elements of $\pi_1(X,p)$, because the endpoints of $g$ and $g'$ may not be kept fixed by it.  However, we do know that at every stage of the homotopy, we have a map $\mathbb{S}^1\to X$, i.e. a loop, so the two endpoints of the path are still equal (they just might not be equal to $p$).  Let $h$ be the path in $X$ given by following how the endpoints move under $H$ (that is, $h(t)=H(0,t)=H(1,t)$ for all $t$).  Then $h$ starts and ends at $p$, since the basepoints of the loops $g$ and $g'$ are both $p$.  So we can think about $h$ as an element of $\pi_1(X,p)$.  What you want to prove now is that $g=hgh^{-1}$, as elements of $\pi_1(X,p)$.  To show this, try and reparamaterize the homotopy $H$ to get a homotopy between $g$ and the concatenation $hgh^{-1}$ (if the domain of $H$ is a square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, $g$ corresponds to the bottom edge, and $hgh^{-1}$ corresponds to going up the left edge, across the top edge, and then down the right edge).

The proof of (1) is similar to (2): you more or less reverse all the steps in the discussion above.