# Conjugate paths have free homotopic circle representations?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is this statement true?

> In a path connected space $X$, conjugate elements of $\pi_1(X,p)$ have free homotopic circle representations.

This is related to my other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548030/bijection-induced-by-mapping-loops-to-their-circle-representations). Basically, I am trying to show that mapping a representative of a conjugacy class to the homotopy class of its circle representative is a well-defined map.

Comment: Yes, the statement is true.

Comment: Could you give an idea of a proof? Is the path connectedness of $X$ important?

Comment: Every statement after the comma lives in a single path component, so not really. This is a good instructional exercise so I'd prefer not to give too much in the way of a hint. Now that you know it's true, try to draw some pictures to see why.

Comment: I think I have a solution, could you check it for errors (below)?

Comment: Let $ [g] $ and $ [g'] $ be two representatives of a conjugacy class $ \mathcal{C} $. Then we have $ [g] = [\overline{h}g'h] $ for some loop $ h $. This means $ g $ is path homotopic to $ \overline{h}g'h $. Denote this path homotopy by $ H \colon I \times I \to X $.

Comment: Under the quotient $ \omega \times \text{id} \colon I \times I \to \mathbb{S}^1 \times I $ we know there exists a unique continuous map $ \tilde{H} \colon \mathbb{S}^1 \times I \to X $ such that $ \tilde{H} \circ (\omega\times \text{id}) = H $. This $ \tilde{H} $ is a homotopy between $ \tilde{g} $ and $ \tilde{g}' $ so conjugate elements have homotopic circle representations.

Comment: Very good. (Make sure to try to see, visually, what's going on. I like using curves in the plane for this, even though the fundamental group is trivial here.) There's also the converse to prove :) If you post this as an answer, I'll upvote it.